# Lazy loading in MongoDB with NoRM

Tags: c#, mongodb, lazy-loading, norm

I have a model similar to this:
(simplified)

**Question:**

```
public class Question
{
    public string QuestionID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

**Answer:**

```
public class Answer
{
    public string QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

I intend to store the data in MongoDB, and would like to use [NoRM](http://github.com/atheken/NoRM) with this.

My question is: Is lazy loading supported? Or can I set it up to do lazy-loading on the document store..?

So that requesting a Question, also retrieves the Answers..?
(both will be "posts" stored in the same collection on MongoDB)

Comment: what you exactly mean lazy loading here??

Comment: I mean - when i retrieve a "question" doc from Mongo, the answers aren't got from the db until tolist() or similar is called...

Comment: How exactly are the questions and answers stored? Are the answers embedded in the question documents? Or is every answer a document on its own?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, the concept of "Lazy Loading" is mostly foreign to a database like MongoDB. Take a look at your schema: `Question` has a `List` of `Answers`.

In an **RDBMS** the "lazy" part allows you to load "the list" separately from the original. There are actually two queries happening, you're just trying to delay the second query.

In **MongoDB** there's only one query happening. The `Answers` are embedded inside of the question, so your request for `Questions` automatically includes the list of `Answers`.

Please take a look at the NORM samples for a better example of this: http://normproject.org/samples

The basic point is that the structure you provided is no longer multiple tables. It's just one collection with embedded documents. So the concept of "Lazy Loading" is really unnecessary because you can't "Lazy Load" one query.

Comment: I don't think I agree. While embedding is certainly often done in mongoDB (maybe even most of the time) there are certainly plenty of times when linking with ids is used as well.  That is the context where lazy loading is relevant.  But I haven't found a perfect answer to this yet myself.

Comment: To be clear, this is an answer to a question regarding a product that is no longer supported :) https://github.com/atheken/NoRM

Comment: Well that is true.  Though I think all of this applies equally to mongoDB with the current 10Gen supported driver.  And as I say I still haven't found a perfect solution yet either.

Answer (score 8):

I appreciate that this is an old thread, but other people may still be finding it (as I did). Lazy loading is both possible in MongoDB and supported by the C# driver.

Check out the following classes: LazyBsonDocument and LazyBsonArray

From the C# Driver tutorial documentation : "The lazy classes are special in that they defer the deserialization of BSON until it is needed. This is useful for when you only need a field or two out of a complex document because it will not incur the cost of deserializing the entire document or array, but just the pieces that are necessary. This deserialization occurs a level at a time."

At the time of writing the tutorial document can be found here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/

The example given is very similar to the question in that it involved a nested collection, so it looks like the list of answers could indeed be lazy loaded if that was desirable.

Hope this helps someone,

Nick

Comment: -1 - this question was about NoRM (the now deprecated MongoDB wrapper / orm) While your answer is correct, it's not in the context of this question.

Comment: Fair enough - I still think the answer adds value as it corrects the wrong assertion in the accepted answer that lazy loading is foreign to MongoDB - so the post is valid in the context of the answer given...